# Expo react native log doesnt appear on console

Tags: react-native, expo

I am having a problem when trying to log fetch json response.
The log doesnt seem to log, last night it was all fine. This morning suddenly that data cat be logged

```
 const fetchResults = async (text, offset = data.length, options = {}) => {
const { timeout = 8000 } = options;
const controller = new AbortController();
const requestUrl = `https://itunes.apple.com/search?limit=30&offset=${offset}&term=${text}`;
console.log(requestUrl);

const res = fetch(requestUrl)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    return res.json()
  })
  .then((res) => {
    // The log below doesnt appear on console
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Request failed', err);
  });
```

};

Can someone help me
https://snack.expo.dev/@aguav/react-songlist-test

Answer (score 1):

I Found it, the limit was too high (30) when i change to 10 it started to show again, maybe the log cant print large data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).